# Apache JMeter Test Script Recorder gRPC HTTP/2 support

Tags: jmeter, grpc, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I want to load test a web application server which communicates through [gRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC) (which uses HTTP/2 for transport) with the clients.

It seems that [Apache JMeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JMeter) extended by the plugin [JMeter gRPC Plugin](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-plugin) and [JMeter gRPC Request](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-request) sampler would be perfect for this.

Among other things JMeter provides a [Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) which helps quickly generate scenarios by acting as a HTTP proxy between the client and the server.

Question 1: Is it possible to use the JMeter Recorder for recording the communication through the gRPC protocol?

Question 2: Is it possible to use the JMeter Recorder for recording the communication through the underlying HTTP/2 protocol?

I have tried already the JMeter Recorder to record the gRPC communication without success :-( Maybe caused by wrong configuration of the recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, at least not with [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)
2. No, as of JMeter 5.5 the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder doesn't support HTTP/2. Neither it does support [.proto](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3) files so even if you record the raw packets you won't be able to decode them into anything meaningful

So I would recommend using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for capturing the packets between client and the system under test and then replicating the same using JMeter's GRPC sampler.